# Determine hostname of client in asyncio socket server

Tags: python, python-asyncio

It looks like there's a way to get an identifier for a plain old socket using `socket.getpeername()`. However, it doesn't look like there's any way to access the socket when using `asyncio.start_server`. Is there any way to obtain a unique identifier (e.g. IP address) of clients for an asyncio socket server?

```
async def client_handler(reader: StreamReader, writer: StreamWriter):
    print("Client connected at {some_ip_address_or_identifier}")  # ?

async def main():
    IP = "0.0.0.0"
    PORT = 8080
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    server = await asyncio.start_server(client_handler, IP, PORT)
    await server.serve_forever()

asyncio.run(main())
```

Comment: mm.. Have you checked the example here?
https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-stream.html. it looks like you can do writer.get_extra_info('peername') to get the address, or am i wrong?

Comment: @ranifisch Ah, thanks, I didn't realize `StreamWriter` had that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can just do:

```
addr =  writer.get_extra_info('peername')
```

according to the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-stream.html)

Comment: Nah this gives you virtually nothing...!